# yii.php: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, ubuntu, yii

I'm trying to install a live wordpress site locally on my Ubuntu machine.  Everything is working ok except for a portion of the site which I believe is built on the YII framework.

When I point the browser to http://localhost.000-wordpress.co/app I get the below error in my apache2 error log:

```
[Sat Jan 18 23:35:55 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/ross/public_html/000-wordpress/public/app/../vendors/yii/framework/yii.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/ross/public_html/000-wordpress/public/app/index.php on line 12, referer: http://localhost.000-wordpress/

[Sat Jan 18 23:35:55 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/ross/public_html/000-wordpress/public/app/../vendors/yii/framework/yii.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/ross/public_html/000-wordpress/public/app/index.php on line 12, referer: http://localhost.000-wordpress/
```

Any idea what I should do, I FTP'd the entire site down from it's online server.

I have no experience of YII, and am only installing the site locally to make some design changes before pushing them to the live site.

Comment: you should open your `/home/ross/public_html/000-wordpress/public/app/index.php` and modify your setting. see where your yii is installed

Comment: You may need to install yii on your server. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.installation

Answer (score 0):

Download the Yii framework and place it somewhere on your computer.
link: http://www.yiiframework.com/

Then make sure the location in index.php (`/home/ross/public_html/000-wordpress/public/app/index.php`) points to the right location. This should be the location where you just placed the downloaded framework. Make sure it points to the yii.php file in the framework folder.

Comment: Thank you jagsler, this helps but I get another error `[error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /home/ross/public_html/000-engaging.co/public/app/dashboard, referer: http://localhost.000-engaging.co/` any idea what I should do here?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use a file that apparently doesn't exist, any idea where the call to this file comes from? and can you verify that the file (doesn't) exist?